# What statistical methods does one use to map movements?

Tags: model, spatial, ecology

I have the movement (given by longitude and latitude) of 5 birds over a period of about a year.

I would like to analyze their movement, i.e. where do they like to spend most of their time. What models can I use for a question like this?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc44.htm . While this is about univariate time series, imho the techniques work for bivariate time series too.